# Changing default Object library attribute values in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Is it possible?  For example, when you drag and drop a new UILabel from the Objects library onto a view, it gets set to System 17.0 Font, Left Justified, Autoshrink enabled, and so on.  Could I make it so all the labels I add from this point on all are Right Justified, for example, so I don't have to change each one as I add it?

Edit: changed terminology from "property" to "attribute"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do know copy-pasting an existing object keeps everything - all the attributes in the pasted one will be whatever they were in the copied one at the time it was copied.  This is not exactly what I'm looking for as it has some pitfalls .  For example, I can imagine a situation where I want all my labels in a project to have the same font style, but different text colors and alignments, so copy-pasting something might actually end up creating more work in the end.

Edit: changed terminology from "property" to "attribute"

Edit 2: From everything I've seen, it looks like copy-paste is the only way to create a new object with non-default attributes.  Marking this as the answer unless anyone comes up with something better.